# “Could not deploy package” error while installing Sitecore 9 update 2 setup on my local enviromment

Tags: xconnect, sitecore-install-framework, deployment, powershell

I am a beginner in sitecore and I am facing the below error while setting up sitecore on my local environment

```
 [-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Info: Adding MsDeploy.Site (MsDeploy.Site).
Info: Adding database (user id=sca;data source=(local);initial catalog=xp0_Processing.Pools)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Pending.
Info: Deploying package to database: Pending.
Info: Creating deployment plan: Running.
Info: Initializing deployment (Start)
Info: Initializing deployment (Failed)
Info: Creating deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Verifying deployment plan: Faulted.
Info: Deploying package to database: Faulted.
Error: Could not deploy package.
**Error: Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
Error: Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.**
Error Code: ERROR_EXECUTING_METHODError count: 1.

More Information: Could not deploy package.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
Internal Error. The database platform service with type Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.Sql130DatabaseSchemaProvider is not valid. You must make sure the service is loaded, or you must provide the full type name of a valid database platform service.
  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_EXECUTING_METHOD.
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\resourcefiles\install.ps1:41 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @xconnectParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:01:18
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\resourcefiles\xconnect-xp0.190611 (6).log
Invoke-CommandTask : Command C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe returned a non-zero exit code - (-1)
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.1\Public\Tasks\Invoke-WebDeployTask.ps1:36 char:2
+     Invoke-CommandTask -Path $Path -Arguments $msdeployArgs -TaskName ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-CommandTask
```

I searched the internet and fount [[this][1](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14038/could-not-deploy-package-error-while-installing-sitecore-9-update-2-setup-on-r)](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/14038/could-not-deploy-package-error-while-installing-sitecore-9-update-2-setup-on-r) question which is quite similar to mine but he was facing this issue on the server, not on the local environment.

I checked I have installed all the prerequisites

I tried the solution given in the question but it didn't solve the issue.

Can anyone please guide me where I am making the mistake, I am trying to setup Sitecore for the last three days, every time I solve an issue new comes up

Thank you

Comment: Can you verify that the version of SQL Server you have installed matches the version expected by Sitecore? I think the error is referring to a 2016 instance of SQL Server.

Comment: @MichaelWest  I have installed sql server 2017 and sql server management studio 2018

Comment: @MichaelWest should I try installing sql server 2016?? Can it resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi @MichaelWest changing the sql server helped, thanx a lot, you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all Sitecore 9.1 prerequisites related to SQL Server are installed as per Sitecore 9.1 installation guideline.

Sitecore 9.1 supports Microsoft SQL Server 2017 and 2016 SP2

You must also install: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server Microsoft Command Line Utilities 13 for SQL Server

If you are running an x64 environment, you must install both the x64 and x86 versions of DacFx and SQLSysCLRTypes.

Comment: Hi @S.Kazmi I am having sitecore 9.0 update 2 not 9.1, I was using sql serverv 2017 and it was cauing issues and changing the sql server to 2016 solved the issue